# Can pseq be defined in terms of seq?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, strictness

As far as I know, `seq a b` evaluates (forces) `a` and `b` before returning `b`. It does not guarantee that `a` is evaluated first.

`pseq a b` evaluates `a` first, then evaluates/returns `b`.

Now consider the following:

```
xseq a b = (seq a id) b
```

Function application needs to evaluate the left operand first (to get a lambda form), and it can't blindly evaluate the right operand before entering the function because that would violate Haskell's non-strict semantics.

Therefore `(seq a id) b` must evaluate `seq a id` first, which forces `a` and `id` (in some unspecified order (but evaluating `id` does nothing)), then returns `id b` (which is `b`); therefore `xseq a b` evaluates `a` before `b`.

Is `xseq` a valid implementation of `pseq`? If not, what's wrong with the above argument (and is it possible to define `pseq` in terms of `seq` at all)?

Comment: If the compiler decides to inline `id` to form `seq a (\x->x)` then it can also see that `\x -> x` is in WHNF so `seq a (\x->x)` could be 'optimized' to just `a`. [`pseq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Conc.Sync.html#pseq) is actually implemented in terms of `seq` and [`lazy`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.19/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0/src/GHC-Magic.html#lazy), which is a 'deeply magical' identity function which the compiler knows to never inline during strictness analysis.

Comment: The magic you are looking for is really in [`lazy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#v:lazy).

Comment: @user2407038 Turning `seq a (\x->x)` into `a` is a type error. Even if it inlines `id`, it would still have to return `\x->x` (and force `a`). That's exactly what I want, isn't it?

Comment: @melpomene Sorry, I meant that `seq a (\x->x) b` can become `seq a ((\x->x) b)` - in general `seq a y o` could become `seq a (y o)` if `y` is in WHNF. Whether the compiler would ever perform such an optimization, I don't know, but it certainly *could*. I believe that in terms of 'raw operational semantics' (i.e. pretending the compiler never changes your code at all) your function is correct - it just breaks down in the presence of optimizations. (indeed, `lazy` is denotationally equal to `id` - so your `xseq` is denotationally equal to `pseq`, and both to `seq`, just not operationally)

Comment: You seem to assume that `f x` must evaluate `f` first to WHNF, but this might not be the case. If the strictness analyzer proves `f` strict, I think the runtime could evaluate `x` first to WHNF without changing the semantics. I'm unsure about whether this actually happens in the GHC optimizer.

Comment: I see that five people have downvoted this question so far. I'd be interested to know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be "no, at least not without additional magic".

The problem with

```
xseq a b = (seq a id) b
```

is that the compiler can see that the result of `seq a id` is `id`, which is strict everywhere. Function application is allowed to evaluate the argument first if the function is strict, because then doing so does not change the semantics of the expression. Therefore an optimizing compiler could start evaluating `b` first because it knows it will eventually need it.

Answer (score 0):

> Can `pseq` be defined in terms of `seq`?

In GHC - yes.

As noted by Alec, you'll also need the mirror-smoke `lazy`:

```
 -- for GHC 8.6.5
import Prelude(seq)
import GHC.Base(lazy)

infixr 0 `pseq`
pseq :: a -> b -> b
pseq x y = x `seq` lazy y
```

the definition matching its counterpart in the GHC sources; the imports are
very different.

For other Haskell implementations, this *may* work:

```
import Prelude(seq)

infixr 0 `pseq`
pseq :: a -> b -> b
pseq x y = x `seq` (case x of _ -> y)
```

*possibly* in conjunction with - at the very least - the equivalent of:

```
 -- for GHC 8.6.5
{-# NOINLINE pseq #-}
```

I'll let melpomene decide if that also qualifies as mirror-smoke...

Comment: Any implementation whose `-O0` does not perform strictness analysis should let you define an inefficient version of `lazy` in its own module. `lazy :: a -> a; lazy x = x {-# NOINLINE lazy #-}`. As long as the module doesn't reveal that `lazy` is actually strict in its argument, and doesn't produce an unfolding for it, you should be good. The GHC special is inlining it in Core Prep, right at the end of the core-to-core compilation pipeline.